# Resetear variables despues de entregar el resultado

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, click

Tengo este js quiero borrar el contenido de var datos despues de entregar el resultado  para usar esa funcion en otro li con el mismo nombre , se puede hacer eso?

```
 $("#idT").click(function () {
                    var datos = {
                        color: $("#idc").val(),
                        observa: $("#observac").val()
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "genera_color.php",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: datos,

                  success: function (result) {
                    $("#grupo").html(result);
                  }
              });
                });
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, ¿A qué te refieres con otro li con el mismo nombre? y ¿A qué función te refieres? Siempre podrías hacer algo como datos = {}; dentro de la función en success, pero no sé muy bien qué es lo que quieres conseguir con todo esto. ¡Saludos!

Comment: lo que quiero es usar la misma function para el efecto click de diferentes <li> pero como seria ya que el el click de otro <li>  las variables que están en datos serian diferentes valores a enviar., puedo resetear a ningun valor despues de entregar las variables?